# What to do if Fast User Switching doesn't work?

Tags: user-accounts, authentication, fast-user-switching

I did all the registry and group policy modifications suggested here: https://winbuzzer.com/2020/08/21/how-to-enable-or-disable-fast-user-switching-in-windows-10-xcxwbt/

But at logon it is still either always to type in username and password, or can log in only with the last logged on user. The user selection on the bottom left corner is missing. The Windows 10 laptop is non domain joined if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue has to do with fast user switching. FUS doesn't apply until you log in at least the first user.

Comment: You can disable it and see if that helps your issue.

Comment: Try to reset Local Security Policy settings to Default. Open an administrative Command Prompt and try the following command: `secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose`.